# npm install chromedriver is not working properly

Tags: node.js, npm, selenium-chromedriver, package.json, uninstallation

Does any one how to install never version of chrome driver besides;

npm install chromedriver,
npm install chromedriver --chromedriver_cdnurl=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver,
npm install chromedriver --chromedriver_version=LATEST ,
npm install chromedriver --chromedriver-force-download

"SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 91
Current browser version is 94.0.4606.71 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

This commands are not working to update chromedriver version. I tried to uninstall it first but I was not able to uninstall chromedriver dependancy.

anyone knows any other command that I can try?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If your trying to update the chromedriver which is latest and not in NPM. Here is the steps.

1. Download the latest version of chromedriver from - https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
2. Intall the chromedriver globally - npm install -g  chromedriver --chromedriver_filepath=/Path for download files /Downloads/chromedriver_mac64.zip2.
3. Latest version of chromedriver will be installed.

Comment: Thank you very Much.I will try that

Comment: I also found another way because command you posted to install chrome driver. doest work all the time. what I did was that I went to package.json file and inside the the chrome driver string,I removed the version and clicked ctrl+space. it automatically showed me the lates version. Then I run npm install and it works totally fine. Thank you very much for your answer again.

Comment: This does not work on Windows. Local zip file chromedriver_win32.zip is not used and you always get only the "latest" 112.0.5615.49 instead of the browser matching 113.0.5672.64

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution !!**

Let's initially understand the problem
Google chrome brings update on regular intervals & If our code runs on older version then it brings compatibility Issues so we need to update the chrome binaries for it.

For Updating chrome driver you need to use the following command

```
npm install chromedriver --chromedriver_version=LATEST
```

But sometimes after you are done with running this command you can face same issue again. It is bit wired so here is the solution for it.

Let me take a example initally "chromedriver": "^109.0.0" was installed now you want to update it to latest version

1. Go to package.json
2. Removed the existing chrome version
3. Now press ctrl+space,you will see the latest package,choose it
4. Again run the below command

   npm install chromedriver--chromedriver_version=LATEST

**Hoping your problem will get resolved**

Keep Learning,Keep Growing & Help Community:)

Comment: as of today 2023-05-04 this does not work. Current version of Chrome is 113.0.5672.63 and all you get with LATEST is 112.0.5615.49

Comment: Hey ,
Today only I updated the chromedriver for my team-mate 
It was easily able to migrate to 113.0
Request to check the steps again 
If not solved let me know . will connect via some medium

Comment: does not work. as of today 9/27/2023 all we get is 114.0.5735.90. This is confirmed by the output of https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE

Comment: Believe me it work . If you want a seperate call . let me know . we can connect . Life without this command is not possible. I am using currently 117.0.1 version chrome driver

Comment: That worked, you have to physically remove the line from the package.json - which I did not do. I trusted `ncu -u`, why doesn't that work?

That's still a problem with Windows scripting, but at least we have a way. Thanks

Ctrl+space == what is it?

Comment: This worked for me. Curious there isn't more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a real pain. As of today 9/27/2023 all we get is 114.0.5735.90, while the current stable release is 117.0.5938.92.

This is confirmed by the output of https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE
Edge driver is up-to-date. Why is Microsoft up-to-date and not Google?

Personally, when one goes out-of-date I use the other.
However, as of today 11/08/2023 **NONE** are available and BOTH are incompatible with the current browser version, as detailed here https://www.it-cooking.com/npm-install-webdriver-is-not-working-properly-3-solutions/

- Edge is version 119.0.2151.44 but driver is 118.0.2088.7 at best
- Chrome is version 119.0.6045.106 but driver is 114.0.5735.90 at best

What do we do now??